# Trouble saving high score in android app

Tags: android

I searched online and people are doing this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int oldScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);  
if(newScore > oldScore ){
   Editor edit = prefs.edit();
   edit.putInt("key", newScore);
   edit.commit();
}
```

But I want to use the first line in a class other than the class that extends Acitivity (it seems the `this.getSharedPreferences` method won't work otherwise). How can I do this?

Comment: Are you working with activity or fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) to the method or the class you want to use `getSharedPreferences()` in like so:

```
public void updateHighScore(Context context, int newScore) {
  SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  int oldScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);  
  if(newScore > oldScore) {
   Editor edit = prefs.edit();
   edit.putInt("key", newScore);
   edit.commit();
  }
}
```

If you really need to, you can use [`getApplicationContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) to provide a context accessible anywhere in the application.

For more informations check out this question ['What is context in Android?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android).

Comment: I used  getApplicationContext()  as my solution. Thanks.